# Android Google maps v1 transition to v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Sorry Im new to Android Development, dont know how to convert google maps v1 to google maps v2, cant find any good source related to transition from one api to another api...

Main thing is to know what api v1 `method/datatype/libs/overlay = to api v2`, I for testing I had created working simple solution of working api v2 `google maps` so i know what should be changed in manifest in loyaut but main problem in Java code and api transition.

Answer (score 0):

Now API has been out to the v3. I suggest you choose v3.